# Getting additional fields from JWT token using WAS Liberty + openidConnectClient, is following solution supported officially?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I'm using `openidConnectClient-1.0` to authenticate users within my application by using OpenID protocol. Basic authentication works fine, but I need to get values of additional fields from JWT token which OpenID provider pass to me.
Found this answer on IBM's dwAnswers site: [Additional fields from JWT using openidConnectClient](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/356740/additional-fields-from-jwt-using-openidconnectclie.html) where were given the following solution:

```
com.ibm.websphere.security.openidconnect.token.IdToken idToken = PropagationHelper.getIdToken(); 
Object claim = idToken.getClaim("");
```

This code works like a charm but I barely find mention of this API on IBM's website, what I have found is only this Javadoc API for Class [PropagationHelper](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/beta/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.oidc_1.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/security/openidconnect/PropagationHelper.html), Javadoc for `IdToken` I didn't find.

So, my question is it official API and will it be supported by future liberty releases and can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is a supported api, because if I unzip the javadoc at 
wlp\dev\api\ibm\javadoc\com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.oauth_1.2-javadoc.zip, it's in that documentation.